# How to convert MongoDB To php

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have this queries in mongodb , but I want to change to execute those query in php 
I'm a bit new in mongodb , can you guys kindly show me 
1.

```js
db.Station.group({
    "key": {
        "OrganizationIdentifier": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "countstar": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
        else prev.countstar++;
    },
    "cond": {
        "OrganizationIdentifier": {
            "$in": ["R10BUNKER", "USGS-CA"]
        }
    }
});
```

2.

```js
db.Station.find({
    "$or": [{
        "StateCode": 11
    }, {
        "CountyCode": 55
    }]
}, {
    "MonitoringLocationIdentifier": 1,
    "MonitoringLocationName": 1,
    "MonitoringLocationDescriptionText": 1
});
```

Comment: Here is the reference to get started with mongo in php. http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

php.net is a great resource for you to get started

MongoDB: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php

MongoCollection::find

```
$projections = array(
    // your projections
    // as in fields you want returned
);

$collection->find(array(
    '$or' => array(
        array('StateCode' => 11),
        array('CountyCode' => 55),
    ),
), $projections);
```

MongoCollection::group

```
$keys = array(
    // your keys
);

$initial = array(
    'countstar' => 0,
);

$reduce = 'function(obj, prev) {
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
    else prev.countstar++;
}';

$options = array(
    'condition' => array(
        // your conditions
    ),
);

$collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce, $options);
```